# How to install a package written by myself?

Tags: packages, package-writing, code, files

I have a question. How can I install a package written by myself with MikTeX?

I first made a `.txt` file than I wrote my package (code) in there. Then I renamed the `.txt` file to `.sty` . What should I do now?

Thank you for your answeres.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764)

Comment: Related: [Where does the documentclass command look for class files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147351/5764)

Answer (score 4):

You should put in some directory in a local TeXMF root. As MiKTeX  doesn't create such a local root by default, you'll have to create one yourself if you haven't already done so *not* the TeXMF root installed by MiKTeX. Then register this new root with MiKTeX Settings--> Root tab:

[image]

You'll have to respect the TDS (TeX Directory Structure): put your .sty file in, say,  `\TeXMF-local\tex\latex\myownfiles\` ; if you create some documentation for it, puit it in `TeXMF-local\doc\latex\myownfiles`. Finally, refreshh the FNBD with MiKTeX Settings, both as administrator and as user:

[image]