# Cygwin's pdflatex several times slower starting some time between 2015 and summer 2019

Tags: pdftex, cygwin

I've used Cygwin's `pdflatex` for the better part of a decade now.
Being a non-administrator, I was locked down to a 2015 installation
for several years.  At around 2019, I was given the opportunity to
update Cygwin, and I think it was around that time that I saw a marked
slow down in `pdflatex`'s processing of LaTeX documents, even small
ones (my document sizes haven't changed much through the years).
Since I work with multiple laptops, I estimate that this started
occuring for me circa summer 2019, plus/minus perhaps 4 months.  It is
possible that the actual slowdown in Cygwin's `pdflatex` started well
before then, with me being stuck in an 2015 installation and
blissfully unaware.

I've done the online web search.  I see complaints dating well before
2019 of Cygwin and various LaTeX processing software being slow, but
no mention of a marked slowdown occuring between 2015 and 2019.

Since I am very much at the user level rather than admin level, I rely
alot on the configuration of Cygwin apps as-installed.  But I
sometimes poke deeper, especially when repeatedly experiencing the
agonizing slowness of compilation.  **What might cause this slowdown,
and what measures can I take to mitigate this?**

I'm seriously considering switching to MiKTeX, even though I would
very much dislike leaving the non-GUI environment of Bash and Vim.

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

- A minimal example file accompanied by the organizational texmf
  subtree compiled slowly too, i.e, with no references or acronyms.
  The console output scrolled very slowly compared to the 2015
  installation.
- In the console output, I sometimes see a single line of what seems
  like page numbers adorned with square brackets print out slowly. My
  naive impression from this is that this slowness is due to
  processing other than file searching.
- I compared timed execution with MiKTeX and found it even slower
  than Cygwin's `pdflatex` (as predicted by Steven B. Segletes & Ulrike Fischer).

  - Erased auxiliary files and ran Bash script `mkpdf.bash`
    containing the usual `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex` x2
  - Timed the execution from **Cygwin's Bash** with `time ./mkpdf.bash`:
    **1m56s**
  - Two tries of *incremental runs* of `pdflatex` using **Cygwin's
    Bash**: **38s, 37s**
    `export TEXMFHOME=texmf`
    `time pdflatex MainDocument.tex`
  - **MiKTeX** with *no "aux" files* (`pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex`):
    **2m18s**
  - Choose *incremental `pdfLaTeX`* beside **MiKTeX** "play" button:
    **43s**

Comment: I think MikTeX's pdflatex slowed down too.  I am presuming it was some change in the engine that brought this about.  However, I only notice it for a custom documentclass that loads a lot of packages.

Comment: I have cygwin texlive 2016 to 2021 pretest  (deleted older ones tro make room so have not got 2015 anymore) and haben't seen any particular slow down. Make sure you are using the ls-R files and not searching the file system every time?

Comment: I use cygwin as it's convenient but probably the native windows texlive woudl be quicker as the cygwin file system layer does have some cost (but mostly if iterating over housands of files, not noticable just working on one document loading a few packages)

Comment: @David Carlisle: I googled TeXLive & am lost.  I found that LaTeX is to TeX what `pdflatex` is to pdfTeX. The TeX Live pages I found say that it is a distribution of TeX, and I assume PdfTex as well. Does Cygwin's `pdflatex` use Tex Live? I also googled `ls-R`; it creates `~/texmf/ls-R`, which I don't have.  I have a my own `texmf` tree in the working folder of my document; it contains no `ls-R`. I Googled `ls-R`, but I think it requires much deeper expertise than I have.  You mentioned using a Windows Tex Live, but if give up on Cygwin, I'll try MiKTeX 1st, since I've used it before.

Comment: Since I have not measured the slowdown, I could not say exactly, but saying it slowed down by a factor of 2x-plus would be in the realm of possibility.  It is particularly noticeable when multiple passes are needed, as when changes in the toc or bibliography occur.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: A 2x slowdown means it's plausible that what I see is due (at least in part) to the engine slowdown that you speculate.  I do use a documentclass designed by other LaTeX experts, but I did so for years before 2015.

Comment: The packages I include grow slowly through the years (always including the `acro` package), so it doesn't explain the several-fold slowdown in upgrading Cygwin.  I can't recall exactly, but there was likely a short period when I had both old and new Cygwin installations, and noticed the speed difference for the same document.  As for which passes are slowest, I do the typical `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, and `pdflatex`(x2). I haven't noticed a difference in slowness between them but will keep an eye out. I do have ToC & list of references.

Comment: miktex is compared to texlive my experience slower, so imho not the best option when speed is important.

Comment: texlive is a cross platform distribution, it has binaries for linux, mac, windows, cygwin or lots of other formats. So on windows you can use the windows binaries or the cygwin ones in cygwin or the linux ones in wsl. in cygwin as in linux you can use the version that comes with cygwin (installed via its setup) or (as I do) get the version from tug.  I would say that any observable slowdown is due to misconfigured file searching rather than a chaneg in the actual program, btut it all depends...

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks. I didn't know the relationship between `pdflatex` and Tex Live.  After rummaging, I am 95% sure that Cygwin relies on Tex Live, and `pdflatex` is part of that or relies on that. If the slowdown is due to misconfigured file search, it would have to be misconfigured out-of-the-box; that's how I use `pdflatex`.  Unless my document-specific `texmf` tree is responsible, and that tree is from my organization's wizards. I suspect that the `texmf` tree is not responsible, however, because all the organization uses copies of it, and I've heard no complaints (they use MiKTeX).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Thanks for sharing your experience with MiKTeK being slower than TeX Live.  I'm suspecting David Carlisle's suggestion that file search is misconfigured rather than TeX Live itself.  I am of the few who prefer command line and Cygwin; the rest of the organization uses copies of the same `texmf` tree, but with MiKTeK.  No one has complained.  Raw speed under normal operation isn't my concern, but rather, black-box speed, including misconfiguration.  Even if MiKTeK is *normally* slower, I will go for it if it avoids this very pronounced slowdown I'm experiencing with Cygwin.

Comment: the cygwin supplied tex is an (older) release of texlive yes. If your document specific texmf tree is large and in front of the standard tex input tree then it will impact file loading times proportional to the size of the texmf tree. as `\documentclass{article}` will have to search the filesystem to check there is no article.cls in your local texmf before using the quick hashed file lookup to access the standard copy.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks! My document-specific `texmf` contains only 34 files, and the custom-named document class is found therein, so it probably isn't the source of the slowdown. I'm starting to wonder if file configuration is the problem.

Comment: In the course of the above, I Googled the order in which folders are searched for a document class and found [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147351/where-does-the-documentclass-command-look-for-class-files), which told me that `ls-R` is located in `texmf-dist`.  I found it at `/usr/share/texmf-dist/ls-R`. It doesn't shed light on the slowdown, but it's nice to find it after failing to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Someone in my organization reported a slowdown of the `acro` package at around the time I first saw it.  I couldn't use the [suggested `[version=2]`](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/205) option because it causes both `exclude` and `exclude-class` options to go unrecognized.  My solution was to disable `acro` package except for document finalization.

Here is the code to conditionally enable/disable the acro package.  A single run of `pdflatex` now takes 13.5 seconds, which is a 3x speedup.  Thanks for everyone's help.

```
% Acronyms
\newif\ifacro
\acrofalse % Replace with \acrotrue to enable acro package
\ifacro
   \usepackage[display-foreign=false]{acro}
      % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499134/calling-acro-first-use-when-plural-is-producing-an-s-in-the-short-definition-t
   \input{acronyms}
\else
   \usepackage{suffix}
   \newcommand{\ac}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \newcommand{\Ac}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \newcommand{\acf}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \newcommand{\Acf}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \newcommand{\acs}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \newcommand{\Acs}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \newcommand{\acl}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \newcommand{\Acl}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \newcommand{\acp}[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \newcommand{\Acp}[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \newcommand{\acsp}[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \newcommand{\Acsp}[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \newcommand{\acfp}[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \newcommand{\Acfp}[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \newcommand{\aclp}[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \newcommand{\Aclp}[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \newcommand{\acresetall}{}
   \newcommand{\acuse}{}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\ac*[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\Ac*[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\acf*[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\Acf*[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\acs*[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\Acs*[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\acl*[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\Acl*[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\acp*[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\Acp*[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\acsp*[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\Acsp*[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\acfp*[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\Acfp*[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\aclp*[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
   \WithSuffix\newcommand\Aclp*[1]{\uppercase{#1}s}
\fi

<...snip...>

\ifacro
   \cleardoublepage
   \printacronyms[%
      name = {List of abbreviations/acronyms/initialisms/symbols},
      sort = false
   ]
\fi
```